# How to Center Align a Graph in R using ggraph with a Manual Layout?

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, igraph, ggraph

I'm attempting to create a centred skill tree visualization using `ggraph` in R, but my graph persists in being left-aligned within the plotting area. The tree is built from a JSON data source specifying each node's `row` and `col`, which I use to create a manual layout for the nodes.

Here's how I set up the graph:

```r
library(jsonlite)
library(igraph)
library(ggraph)

file_path <- "./nodes.json"
mastery_tree_data <- fromJSON(file_path)

graph <- make_empty_graph(directed = TRUE)

# Add nodes
for (node_id in names(mastery_tree_data)) {
  node_info <- mastery_tree_data[[node_id]]
  label_text <- paste(node_info$name, "\nLvl", node_info$current_level, "/", node_info$max_level)
  graph <- add_vertices(graph, 1, name = node_id, label = label_text)
}

# Add edges
for (node_id in names(mastery_tree_data)) {
  node_info <- mastery_tree_data[[node_id]]
  if (!is.null(node_info$children)) {
    for (child_id in node_info$children) {
      if (child_id %in% names(mastery_tree_data)) {
        graph <- add_edges(graph, c(node_id, child_id))
      }
    }
  }
}

# Manual layout based on the 'row' and 'col' values from JSON
manual_layout <- data.frame(
  name = names(mastery_tree_data),
  x = sapply(mastery_tree_data, function(x) x$col),
  y = sapply(mastery_tree_data, function(x) x$row),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

This is what the ggraph skill tree currently looks like:
[ggraph skill tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSYTD.png)

It appears that despite the positions I've specified, the graph is not centred as intended. I am struggling to find a solution within the functionalities of `ggraph` to correct this.

To address the alignment issue, I calculated the midpoint of the `x` coordinates and attempted to shift the graph so that it would be centred in the plotting area.

Here's the specific code I used for that:

```r
manual_layout$name <- as.character(manual_layout$name)
current_midpoint_x <- mean(manual_layout$x)
desired_midpoint_x <- 0 # We want to center the graph at x = 0
shift_x <- desired_midpoint_x - current_midpoint_x
manual_layout$x <- manual_layout$x + shift_x

# Set x limits for some padding around the nodes
x_range <- max(manual_layout$x) - min(manual_layout$x)
x_padding <- 0.1 * x_range
x_lim <- c(min(manual_layout$x) - x_padding, max(manual_layout$x) + x_padding)

plot <- ggraph(graph, layout = 'manual', node.positions = manual_layout) +
 geom_edge_link() +
 geom_node_point(size = 3) +
 geom_node_text(aes(label = name), repel = TRUE, size = 3) +
 expand_limits(x = x_lim) +
 theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1, 1, 1, 1), "cm"))

print(plot)
```

I expected this to reposition my graph so that it's centred in the plotting area. Instead, the graph remains left-aligned, with no visible changes to its position. I am not sure why the `expand_limits` and `theme` adjustments are not centring the graph as intended.

I've tried several approaches to alter the layout, but the graph still doesn't align to the center. Any guidance on how to properly center a graph in `ggraph` with a manual layout would be highly appreciated.

I don't really know how to use `dput()`, so here's a shortened and compacted version of my JSON instead, I hope this is alright:

```json
{"Node1":{"name":"Attack","parents":[],"children":["Node2_1","Node2_2"],"current_level":0,"max_level":3,"row":1,"col":1},"Node2_1":{"name":"Gold Loot","parents":["Node1"],"children":["Node3_1","Node3_2"],"current_level":0,"max_level":3,"row":2,"col":1},"Node2_2":{"name":"Health","parents":["Node1"],"children":["Node3_3"],"current_level":0,"max_level":3,"row":2,"col":2},"Node3_1":{"name":"Health","parents":["Node2_1"],"children":["Node4"],"current_level":0,"max_level":3,"row":3,"col":1},"Node3_2":{"name":"Idle Earnings","parents":["Node2_1"],"children":["Node4"],"current_level":0,"max_level":4,"row":3,"col":2},"Node3_3":{"name":"Gold Loot","parents":["Node2_2"],"children":["Node4"],"current_level":0,"max_level":3,"row":3,"col":3},"Node4":{"name":"Attack","parents":["Node3_1","Node3_2","Node3_3"],"children":[],"current_level":0,"max_level":3,"row":4,"col":1}}
```

I've also tossed the whole script on GitHub Gists:
[mastery_tree_visualiser.r](https://gist.github.com/gmifflen/33ebf976503c454f28f658d91f3c8cb5)

And here's is the whole JSON file on PrivateBin, just in case
(unused key:values are artifacts from when I was doing this in PHP):
[nodes.json](https://privatebin.net/?98cbe16988ac4a6e#FWNA6oXbeHwfXLkrUEkCkWqRsQaw69rDGxbo89AWQvKH)

(PrivateBin is an open source pastebin alternative)

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here. The nodes in your graph are placed exactly where you are telling ggraph to put them. This _is_ the layout specified by your row and column numbers. Can you explain what you mean about having the graph centered?

Comment: Also, note that this is _not_ a tree. Each node in a tree can only have one parent.

Comment: @AllanCameron The best way I can think to describe what I mean by centred, would be like a paragraph in MSWord/LibreOffice. My current skill "tree" would be a 'left aligned paragraph', while I'm looking to have the skill "tree" be a 'center aligned paragraph'.

and yeah, in video games it is called a "skill tree" despite not being a graph-theoretical definition of a tree

This is what I'm trying to emulate programatically instead of with gimp: [skill_tree.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qwUe.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are essentially looking for your nodes to be 'centre justified', which requires recalculating the x positions. I would perhaps simplify the graph creation a bit:

```r
library(tidygraph)
library(ggraph)

edges_out <- lapply(names(mastery_tree_data), function(x) {
  kids <- mastery_tree_data[[x]]$children
  if(length(kids) > 0) {
    return(data.frame(from = x, to = kids))
  }
})

edges_in <- edges_out <- lapply(names(mastery_tree_data), function(x) {
  mum <- mastery_tree_data[[x]]$parents
  if(length(mum) > 0) {
    return(data.frame(from = mum, to = x))
  }
})

g <- do.call('rbind', c(edges_in, edges_out)) |>
  igraph::graph.data.frame()
```

Then, manipulate the x positions and plot:

```r
as_tbl_graph(g) %>%
  mutate(value = sapply(name, \(x) paste0(mastery_tree_data[[x]]$name, '\n',
                                          mastery_tree_data[[x]]$current_level,
                                          '/',
                                          mastery_tree_data[[x]]$max_level))
                        ) %>%
  mutate(col = sapply(name, \(x) mastery_tree_data[[x]]$col),
         row = as.integer(sapply(name, \(x) mastery_tree_data[[x]]$row))) %>%
  group_by(row) %>%
  mutate(col = row_number()) %>%
  mutate(col = (col - median(col))/n()) %>%
  ggraph(layout = 'manual', x = col, y = row) +
  geom_edge_diagonal(color = 'gray') +
  geom_node_point(color = 'steelblue', size = 5) +
  geom_node_text(aes(label = value), size = 3, repel = TRUE) +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! 
I've also now learned a new way to do graph creation and how to manipulate node positions!

Comment: some connections are a little off or missing, but that's likely my fault and shouldn't be too hard to fix